# Navigation Bar Large Title Problem on some View's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm developing an iOS app, I created some view with TabBar Controller, and I want to use Large Navigation Bar on some View's.

I have three VC on TabBar Controller :

- FeedVC
- ChatsVC
- ProfilesVC

I will use normal Navigation Bar on ( FeedVC ), and I will use Large Navigation Bar on ( ChatsVC, ProfilesVC ).

the problem is when I tap the ChatsVC from FeedVC, it show normal NavigationBar until I scroll down, but when I tap ChatsVC from ProfilesVC is shows Large.

Here is a recorded video of that :
[Video uploaded to my CDN](https://pertuk.b-cdn.net/LPGZ9894.mp4)

The code I use on FeedVC :

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
    self.tabBarController?.title = "Feed"
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically Way, configure Your tab bar controller like this and hide tabBar navigation bar:

```
class TabBarCobtroller: UIViewController {

let yourTabBar = UITabBarController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    yourTabBar.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true // hide the navigation bar of the tab bar
    yourTabBar.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    createTabBarController()
}

func createTabBarController() {
    
    let firstVc = FirstVCController()
    firstVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house.fill"), tag: 1)
    
    let secondVc = SecondVcController()
    secondVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Chats", image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), tag: 1)
    
    let thirdVc = ThirdViewController()
    thirdVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Profile", image: UIImage(systemName: "person.fill"), tag: 1)
    
    let controllerArray = [firstVc, secondVc, thirdVc]
    yourTabBar.viewControllers = controllerArray.map{ UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: $0)}
    
    self.view.addSubview(yourTabBar.view)
 }
}
```

Now add this extension for custom navBar:

```
extension UIViewController {
func configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: UIColor, backgoundColor: UIColor, tintColor: UIColor, title: String, preferredLargeTitle: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: largeTitleColor]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgoundColor
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = preferredLargeTitle
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationItem.title = title
        
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = backgoundColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationItem.title = title
    }
  }
}
```

After that in your FeedVC configure in viewWillAppear your custom nav bar with normal title for this controller:

```
coverride func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .red, tintColor: .white, title: "FeedVC", preferredLargeTitle: false)
}
```

for chatsVC with Large title:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .red, tintColor: .white, title: "ChatsVC", preferredLargeTitle: true)
}
```

For profile with large title:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .white, backgoundColor: .mediumBlue, tintColor: .white, title: "ProfilesVC", preferredLargeTitle: true)
}
```

now you have control of your bar, just edit the line:

```
configureNavigationBar(largeTitleColor: .yourColor, backgoundColor: .yourColor, tintColor: .yourColor, title: "YourVCName", preferredLargeTitle: true) // true if you want large title or falsa if you want normal title...
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why are you hiding the tabbar in the code?